# Can Network throttling from browser restrict upload bandwidth?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, bandwidth, throttling

In Chrome Developer Tools, there is an option for throttling under the Network tab. 
I know it is used to test website performance and that it restricts network bandwidth for downloading the site. My query however is, does it also limit the upload bandwidth and speed? Does it apply to the complete network layer or only to the browser application?

Comment: You may be able to test this using common speed test sites like Ookla.  Test normally ( perhaps you'll get 40/10 ).  Turn on the limiter to 1 and try again - perhaps you'll get 40/10, perhaps 1/10, perhaps 1/1 .  Most likely, the Chrome throttling will only affect Chrome, but it will be good to be sure.  One of the things you can do at SuperUser is test your own Questions and put in your own Answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome 80, you add network throttling profiles through the dev tools and these do restrict the upload speeds as well.